# Invalid keystore format with Flutter

Tags: flutter

I don't know how this could have happened but this is the first time that I am in trouble with Keytool for certificates.
When I try to type in the terminal:

```
keytool -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

I received this error and cannot get fingerprint for Firebase

```
Errore keytool: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
```

Answer (score 0):

After Running Flutter -v in android studio found out that:
Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840) which indicated that there was a difference with the java version installed (was currently using java 1.8).
You can solve the problem by installing the same java version (In my case 11.0.12) and adding it to the PATH in environmental variables.